# Customer user model error; ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am very new to using Django and I am trying to make a custom user model for my Android app. Unfortunately the custom user class is necessary. I keep encountering this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account'
[26/Feb/2020 02:38:13] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 132779
```

I have been searching but cannot find how to fix this. My app is called capp and below are my files

my models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, custom_pin, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email), first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
            custom_pin=custom_pin)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email), password=password, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="first name", max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="last name", max_length=60)
    custom_pin = models.CharField(verbose_name="pin", max_length=4)
    date_of_birth = models.CharField(verbose_name="date of birth", max_length=8)
    # date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    # last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'


    objects = AccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    # For checking permissions. to keep it simple all admin have ALL permissions
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin`
'''
```

my views.py file in my api folder

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view


from capp.api.serializers import RegistrationSerializer
from capp.models import Account

@api_view(['POST', ])
def registration_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}

        if serializer.is_valid():
            account = serializer.save()
            data['response'] = 'successfully registered new user.'
            data['email'] = account.email

        else:
            data = serializer.errors
        return Response(data)
```

my urls.path file in my api folder

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    registration_view,)

app_name = 'capp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('register', registration_view, name="register"),
]
```

my seralizers.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from capp.models import Account #Card, Device, Admin, ATM, History


class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # adding password2 because it is not part of the registration model
    # making it a password field means users wont be able to read it
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Account

        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'custom_pin', 'password', 'password2']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }

    def save(self):
        account = Account(
            email=self.validated_data['email']
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']

        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match.'})
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()
        return account
```

my urls.py file in my project folder

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from capp.api.views import registration_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', registration_view, name='register'),
    path('api/capp/', include('capp.api.urls')),
]
```

my settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ty%lz0ci4j9g2_l!7h&l^lq&wv!a9qee8n43%2n_%(=wr29fo('

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

# use * to allow hosts from anywhere
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # custom apps
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'capp',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', )
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'capp.Account'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend',
    'account.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend',
    )

ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_USER_EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True

REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    "USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER": "users.serializers.CustomUserDetailsSerializer",
}
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    "REGISTER_SERIALIZER": "users.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer",
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Comment: are you encountering this error when creating a superuser from the terminal? because the error has occurred at "/admin/login".

Comment: The error occurs when I try to go to 127.0.0.1:8000/admin

Answer (score 0):

the Model names are case sensitive
--observing your models.py file the model named as 'Account'

check the seralizers.py file not a proper complete model assignment to the variable
this line raising error as 'accounts' used as model in code.